# IStaticPortMappingCollection::Add always returns HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_BUSY)

Tags: windows, upnp

I'm trying to use the Windows UPnP APIs to map an external port to an internal one.  UPnP is enabled and working with software installed on my system but I can't seem to get it working in my own code.  The call looks something like this:

```
wrl::ComPtr< IStaticPortMappingCollection > staticPortMappings;
auto res = sm_impl->upnpNat->get_StaticPortMappingCollection( &staticPortMappings ); 
// Where sm_impl->upnpNat is a previously initialized IUPnPNAT pointer.

long ct = 0;
staticPortMappings->get_Count( &ct );

wrl::ComPtr< IStaticPortMapping > portMapping;

res = staticPortMappings->Add(
    port,
    CComBSTR( protocol.c_str( ) ).m_str,
    port,
    CComBSTR( clientName.c_str( ) ).m_str,
    VARIANT_TRUE,
    CComBSTR( description.c_str( ) ).m_str,
    &portMapping
);
```

res will always be HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_BUSY).  The MSDN documentation does not list this as a typical return code and does not explain why one would get this return code or what to do about it.

Comment: MSDN documents a fixed set of possible failed return values, are you sure it's ERROR_BUSY? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366148(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The HRESULT is 0x800700aa, which is equivalent to HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_BUSY) and isn't an explicit HRESULT value in winerror.h.  0x800700aa is not equivalent to one of the expected error values listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It means the external port number (first parameter from staticPortMappings->Add) is already in use. Try adding another port.